# Ebean generates sql with undercase_notation not CamelCase as expected

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm setting up a Play! 2 application with an already existing db. The entities have been ported to the new app.  When running the application I get a **PersistenceException** since
the sql generated by ebean uses undercase_notation and not CamelCase as it did in my
previous application. So my **restfulIdentifier** property becomes **restful_identifier_id**
instead of **restfulIdentifier_id**.

I have read the documentation at http://www.avaje.org/ebean/getstarted_props.html but I can't find the settings.

**Stack:**

```
PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Unknown column 't0.restful_identifier_id'
in 'field list' Bind values:[200926947] Query was: select t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t0.state c2,
t0.restful_identifier_id c3 from company t0 where t0.id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the meta data of the Entity to tell JPA that your columns have a different name now. Either you are using Annotations or XML files. However you need to compile the sources (or at least enahnce it) to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question but Ebean has 2 naming convention implementations - UnderscoreNamingConvention and MatchingNamingConvention ... and MatchingNamingConvention would provide the camel case convention you are after.

So again, the answer would be to do

```
  MatchingNamingConvention namingConvention = new MatchingNamingConvention();

  ServerConfig serverConfig = ...
  serverConfig.setNamingConvention(namingConvention);
```